# issues run test command on attention OCR tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, ocr

I am new to tensorflow.
I have install tensorflow on my windows machine.
I have import attention ocr from github train was run successfully.
When I run test command on console the error was raised:

> NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Tensor name
>   "bidirectional_rnn/bw/basic
>   _lstm_cell/kernel" not found in checkpoint files D:\TF\OCR\Attention-OCR-master\ model\translate.ckpt-47200
>
> [[Node: save/RestoreV2_2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:l ocalhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_2/tensor_n ames, save/RestoreV2_2/shape_and_slices)]]

[The full code can be found here](https://github.com/da03/Attention-OCR/issues/53).

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi Engineero, Thanks for edit the question. I have to test using my system trained model checkpoint data.it works fine but result is not generated.

Comment: My checkpoint cycle 7000. i download checkpoint model from http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yuntiand/model.tgz ckpt-47200 it raises above error.may be operating system problem?.i trained using windows and external model using Linux .please give me any suggestion.